# Location of move_group_interface for UR5

Tags: ros, moveit, move-group-interface, ur5, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm trying to control an UR5 via MoveIt! in Indigo on a Linux Ubuntu 14.04 system.

I did all the tutorials of ROS and [Getting-Started with an UR5](http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20a%20Universal%20Robot%20and%20ROS-Industrial). And I do find the tutorial for [Move Group Interface/C++ API](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/src/doc/move_group_interface_tutorial.html). And there I understand the single points described.

But I do not understand which file exactly I have to change here. Where can I find or where do I have to build this file? Is it somewhere in the catkin-workspace or somewhere in opt/ros/...

Did I miss a tutorial at some point where this is described?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204066/location-of-move_group_interface-for-ur5/) by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2015-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think, I understand it now. I just can build this file anywhere in the catkin-workspace and just have catkin_make the workspace after changing it.

It's really well explained what's in the file, but in my opinion it misses the information, where this file should be.

---

Originally posted by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) with karma: 236 on 2015-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-03-31**:
Glad you resolved the issue by yourself. Suggestion should be the most welcomed at the repository of the package you used.